# Global Scope Issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have a question regarding a codingame problem. I solved it but do not understand why exactly the solution works.
The link to the problem is [here](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/power-of-thor-episode-1)

The correct code is as follows:

```
light_x, light_y, initial_tx, initial_ty = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
tx = initial_tx
ty = initial_ty

# game loop
while True:
    remaining_turns = int(input())  # The remaining amount of turns Thor can move. Do not remove this line.
    dirx = ""
    diry = ""

    if(ty > light_y):
        diry = "N"
        ty -= 1
    elif(ty < light_y):
        diry = "S"
        ty += 1
    if(tx > light_x):
        dirx = "W"
        tx -= 1
    elif(tx < light_x):
        dirx = "E"
        tx += 1
    
    # Write an action using print
    # To debug: print("Debug messages...", file=sys.stderr, flush=True)
    print(diry + dirx)

    # A single line providing the move to be made: N NE E SE S SW W or NW
```

This gives me the correct solution and allows me to progress into further tests.

The problem that I do not fully understand: though I think it's a global scope issue is if I move the variables "diry" or "dirx"

For example this doesn't work:

```
light_x, light_y, initial_tx, initial_ty = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
tx = initial_tx
ty = initial_ty
dirx = ""
diry = ""
# game loop
while True:
    remaining_turns = int(input())  # The remaining amount of turns Thor can move. Do not remove this line.
    

    if(ty > light_y):
        diry = "N"
        ty -= 1
    elif(ty < light_y):
        diry = "S"
        ty += 1
    if(tx > light_x):
        dirx = "W"
        tx -= 1
    elif(tx < light_x):
        dirx = "E"
        tx += 1
    
    # Write an action using print
    # To debug: print("Debug messages...", file=sys.stderr, flush=True)
    print(diry + dirx)

    # A single line providing the move to be made: N NE E SE S SW W or NW
```

What exactly is the difference between where I put the dirx and diry locations? What is it doing to my code? Apologies if this is an obvious question as I am new to coding and general and am trying to learn.

Comment: It's not a scoping issue, the issue is that in the second version you are not clearing `diry` and `dirx`  in each iteration of the loop and so (for example) once you set `dirx = 'E'` it will remain that value until it changes to `W`. You could work around that by adding a second `elif` clause which sets `dirx = ''` (and the same for `diry`)

Comment: The ONLY difference would happen if `tx` is exactly equal to `light_x` or `ty` is exactly equal to `light_y`.  In that case, neither of your `if` statements will match, and `dirx` or `diry` will be left over from the last loop, instead of starting from empty.

Comment: The working version resets `dirx` and `diry` on every iteration.  The non-working version doesn't - so if you (for example) moved horizontally on one iteration and then vertically on the next, you end up with a diagonal move because the previous value of `dirx` is still around.  ("Global scope" has absolutely nothing to do with this - there are no functions in the code you posted, so everything is necessarily in the global scope.)